# initializing 2d vector using uniform initialization {}

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-languages, 2d-vector

How can i add functionality to initialize this 2dvector class:-

```
template <typename T>
class uvector2d 
{
public:
uvector2d(size_t xAxis=0, size_t yAxis=0, T const & 
t=T()) : xAxis(xAxis), yAxis(yAxis), data(xAxis*yAxis, t)  
{}

T & operator()(size_t xNum, size_t yNum) 
{return data[xNum*yAxis+yNum];}
T const & operator()(size_t xNum, size_t yNum)    
const      {return data[xNum*yAxis+yNum];}
private:
size_t xAxis,yAxis;
uvector<T> data; 
};
```

using uniform initialization as shown below:-

```
vector<vector<int> > vect{ { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                           { 4, 5, 6 }, 
                           { 7, 8, 9 } };
```

i am current using something like:
    uvector2dvect(3,3);
    vect(1,1)=10864;

Comment: Define a constructor that have a parameter of type `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>>` and copy its elements into `data`.

Comment: @DanielLangr The answer section is  below ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe an answer should be much more verbose and explain why something works as a solution. I don't have time to write it now, so I just put a quick hint as a comment :).

Comment: @DanielLangr hi, i created this    cuvector2d(initializer_list<initializer_list<T>> values);

Comment: but is unable to copy to data. can u pls type the code it will be really helpfu

Comment: @user9318103 I cannot help you with copying data into `data` if I don't know what `uvector` is. Can you show us what you have tried and explain why is it _unable to copy data_?

Comment: uvector is a vector implimentation for performance, the vector is uninitialized by default thus saving cpu cycle http://andreoffringa.org/?q=uvector

Comment: @user9318103 And why are you unable to copy data? What have you tried? What does not work?

Comment: @Daniel like this,will this work::        uvector2d(initializer_list<initializer_list<T>> values)
    {copy(values.begin(),values.end(),data.begin());}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a constructor that accepts initializer list of initializer lists as a parameter:

```
uvector2d(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list);
```

Within this constructor, you just need to copy list elements into one-dimensional `data` member vector.

```
uvector2d(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list)
    : xAxis(list.size()), yAxis(list.begin()->size()) {
  data.reserve(xAxis * yAxis);
  for (const auto& inner_list : list)
    for (const auto& element : inner_list);
      data.push_back(element);
}
```

Note that this will work only if inner lists are of the *same size* (which is the only case that makes sense). Also, your storage of elements in 2D vectors seems to be *column-major*, so I suppose the initializer represents a list of columns. If it is actually a list of rows, then you need to transpose:

```
uvector2d(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list)
    : yAxis(list.size()), xAxis(list.begin()->size()) {
  data.resize(xAxis * yAxis);
  size_t y = 0;
  for (const auto& inner_list : list) {
    size_t x = 0;
    for (const auto& element : inner_list); {
      data[x * yAxis + y] = element;
      x++;
    }
    y++;
  }
}
```

I have no option to try this code with `uvector`, so please report any problems if they happen to appear.

Comment: yeah daniel it is not working so for your reference i uploaded all the code for uvector and what i did https://github.com/anu-ShOcKwAvE/stack-overflow-question

Comment: @user9318103 Your initialization is wrong, it even doesn't compile. Learn some basics about C++. You can either use constructor arguments for initialization `(3,3)`, or _braced-init-list_ `{ ... }`, but not both. Also, `[0][1]` element cannot equal 1, `[0][0]` element will equal 1. Note that there was a typo in my code, see the updated answer. Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/AsAZfgjVXy9L84QW

Comment: yeah i know daniel that it won't compile but you see i wanted u vector2d to behave like this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/2d-vector-in-cpp-with-user-defined-size/ that's what the question was all about

Comment: @user9318103 It works: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q48JAJhnTp4tJBpI. You just didn't provide `size` member functions for both dimensions and access elements by function call operator instead of by indexing operator.

Comment: Thank you daniel.:)

Comment: @user9318103 You're welcome. If you like my answer, please upvote and eventually make it accepted. This is how we thank people here :)

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You should `std::initializer_list`. It's class which functionality in short words is to scale many argument which are the same types. You have to create new c-tor which will have in argument `std::initializer_list`.

### Introduction

From C++11 we have new way of object initialization:

```
int x(0);    // old way, rarely used
int y = 0;   // old way, most common
int z{ 0 };  // new way, bracing initialization
```

Bracing initialization is know also as unificaion initialization. For more about this topic I will recommend you [Effective Modern C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996) - exactly point 7.

Bracing initialization have strong typed using `std::initializer_list` (same situation as with `auto`. It's reason why when you use:

```
vector<vector<int> > vect{ { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                           { 4, 5, 6 }, 
                           { 7, 8, 9 } };
```

You got construtor of vector using [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

### Answer

Now if we know how bracket initialization works we know that if we will have any c-tor with `std::initializer_list` then it will be called if can be. Example how you can do it:

```
class ThreeNumbers
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
public:
    ThreeNumbers(std::initializer_list<int> list)
    {
        std::initializer_list<int>::iterator it = list.begin();
        x = *it++;
        y = *it++;
        z = *it;
    }
};
```